# Tizen application is not installing on target device

Tags: installation, tizen

I built the Tizen sample application in wearable IDE 2.3.1 and 2.3.0. I was able to run it on the emulator. But the same application is not installing on my 2.3 wearable target device. While installing, it gives errors. I tried the procedures below for installing the application.

```
*  sdb install app
*  wrt-installer -i app (For installing web application)
```

These are the error messages I got:

```
E/WRT_INSTALLER(  513): pkgmgr_signal.cpp: setPkgname(164) >
    [SECURE_LOG] name is empty

D/WRT_INSTALLER(  513): task_configuration.cpp: hasExtension(85) >   [SECURE_LOG] Looking for extension .xml in 
    /opt/home/developer/WearableUI.wgt

D/WRT_INSTALLER(  513): widget_unzip.cpp: getDecryptedPackage(265) > [SECURE_LOG] Check DRM...

D/WRT_INSTALLER(  513): widget_unzip.cpp: isDRMPackage(171) > [SECURE_LOG] Enter : isDRMPackage()

E/WRT_INSTALLER(  513): widget_unzip.cpp: isDRMPackage(180) > [SECURE_LOG] Cannot open /usr/lib/libdrm-service-core-tizen.so!
```

I have one more concern: Is the `libdrm-service-core-tizen.so` library required for installing applications on Tizen? (For now we are using software rendering.)
Are there any command line tools for installing Tizen native/web apps?

Comment: Fixed grammar and formatting. Made more concise.

Answer (score 0):

This log is not enough to know the exact cause. WRT installer is to continue the installation regardless of the existence of the .so file. I think that will have more direct cause behind the log. Find and send more log.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am sharing the log file link below. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1gRacnJeUVIYW9nbU0yMFZIN0k/view